# Search command using session variable asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a name stored in a session variable called "name".
I have written the statement:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select empID from emp where empFirstName=' "+
                         Session["name"].ToString() + " '", connstring);
da.Fill(ds);
```

I have verified that the session variable is not empty. Yet i am not able to fetch the empID of the record that exists in the table. Is this statement correct?

Comment: You should use `SqlDataReader` to retrive data from the dataset.

Comment: @ghassenfst You did a wrong edit..you replaced `'` with `"`

Comment: what do you think about this  empFirstName=' " @Vishal Suthar

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces at the beginning and end of the string variable in SQL statement.

Try this, it should work:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select empID from emp where empFirstName='"+
                     Session["name"].ToString() + "'", connstring);
```

Comment: Yes it worked. it was a silly mistake  of adding spaces. Thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the spaces over here:

```
' " + Session["name"].ToString() + " '"
 ^                                  ^
 |                                  |
```

that is why the values are suffixed and prefixed by a blank space.

You should try:

```
da =  new SqlDataAdapter (
"Select empID from emp where empFirstName='" + Session["name"].ToString() + "'",
connstring);

da.Fill(ds);
```